# How to embed a Lightning Component as a Visualforce tab?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, lightning

I am pretty new to Salesforce and have a question regarding putting a lightning component inside a visual force page as a tab. Currently I have a visual force page with multiple tabs

```
 <apex:page showHeader="true" tabstyle="my Tabs" 
 <apex:includeLightning />
 <div class="slds">
      <apex:form > 
      <apex:commandButton .... >
      .
      .
      </apex:form>
 </div>

 <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!blah blah}" id="Tab1">
            <c:a component...
  .
  .
```

Now what I want to do is add another tab, and put one of my other Lightning components as its content. Is this possible as a tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lightning Out to accomplish this. Salesforce has great documentation on it here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm.

Comment: I am embarrassed I didn't see this before. Thanks!